# following code comipling perfectly but showing runtime error . why?

Tags: c++, exception

//sample.h

```
int calci(int &value)
{
   if(value < 20)
    throw value;
   else
     return value;
}

class XYZ
{
   int m_x;
   public: XYZ(int &x)try:m_x(x-calci(x))
          {
          }catch (int &a)
          {}

};
class ABC
{
   int m_a;
   public: ABC():m_a(0)
   {
   }
    void foo()
    {
        XYZ xyz(10);


    }
};




int main()
{
   ABC abc;
   abc.foo();
}
```

//if i replace foo() with following code then it works well

```
void foo()
{
  try{
    XYZ xyz(10);
  }catch(...){}
}
```

Comment: its public: XYZ(int &x)try:m_x(x-calci(x)) in line 11

Comment: @user323422 I also see that you've asked 13 questions and not accepted a single answer.

Comment: @Andreas Brinck thanx i got the point but hoe to accept answer idon't know

Comment: @user323422 Click the checkbox on the left of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 5):

From: http://gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm

> What's less obvious, but clearly
>   stated in the standard, is that if the
>   catch block does not throw (either
>   rethrow the original exception, or
>   throw something new), and control
>   reaches the end of the catch block of
>   a constructor or destructor, then the
>   original exception is automatically
>   rethrown.

From standard 15.3/16

> The exception being handled is
>   rethrown if control reaches the end of
>   a handler of the function-try-block of
>   a constructor or destructor.
>   Otherwise, a function returns when
>   control reaches the end of a handler
>   for the function-try-block (6.6.3).
>   Flowing off the end of a
>   function-try-block is equivalent to a
>   return with no value; this results in
>   undefined behavior in a
>   value-returning function (6.6.3).